# Method not allowed. Must be one of the POST slim 3

Tags: php, slim

This is my route

```
$app->post('/place_c', 'place_c_controller:place_c', 
function  ($request, $response, $db_connect) {

return $response;
})->setName('place_c');
```

JavaScript Code

```
$("#frm_place_c").ajaxForm({
             url:   "http://localhost/pub/place_c",
             dataType:  "text",
             beforeSubmit:  _Request, 
             success:       _Response, 


      });





function _Request(formData, jqForm, options) { 

   $(".loader").show();
   return true; 
}     
function _Response(responseText)  { 

$(".loader").hide();


}
```

And I am posting data to the controller /place_c through ajax but i am getting 500 internal server  error "Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST" However using $app->get works perfectly fine. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: The post method on app has only 2 parameters not 3.

Comment: tried that. still the same

Comment: Look at you JavaScript console what request you are actually doing and what url. Especially check if you are doing OPTIONS request for CORS preflight.

Comment: its a POST request.

Comment: Could you please share the JavaScript code?

Comment: check the question please

Answer (score 0):

The server response data  was different than what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064254/slim-framework-method-not-allowed-must-be-one-of-post-405)

Basically, your route specified a `POST` request. Therefore, in your `AJAX` request, you might want to add a method attribute to the object, like so:

```
   $("#frm_place_c").ajaxForm({
         url:   "http://localhost/pub/place_c",
         dataType:  "text",
         beforeSubmit:  _Request, 
         success:       _Response, 
         method: "POST"


  });
```