# Slim Framework Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST (405)

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I have written REST api in slim framework. When i call authenticate API from browser it troughs **'Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST'**. Below is my code, please correct me where i went wrong.

**Index.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'Authenticate.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/api/authenticate', \Authenticate::class);

$app->run();
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**URL**

```
http://localhost/project/api/authenticate
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you type the URL in the browser, the method is going to be `GET` instead of `POST`. What you can do is use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or other alternatives of your choice to test your REST API for other methods like `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.

More info about HTTP methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great. Can you accept my answer if it answers your question? @ImDrPatil